# Inline css not working on Flutter, package: flutter_html

Tags: html, css, flutter, dart, package

I am trying to display an HTML string with **inline CSS** in flutter using the **Flutter_Html** package. But It is not styling my text according to my inline CSS, It just showing depending on the tags.

Here is my code

```dart
Html(
   data: """<p>Hello <span style="color: #fbeeb8; background-color: #e03e2d;">World</span></p>""",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some other packages. You can try those.

[simple_html_css](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_html_css)

[flutter_widget_from_html](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/flutter_widget_from_html)

Comment: while links as answer are OK, please provide some sort information, why this would solve the problem, so others could take advantage from it.

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles are not released yet for `flutter_html`, but will be soon (as discussed on [this issue](https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html/issues/536)), but you may use master branch override if you already want to use it.